# JavaFX combo box style button if editable

Tags: java, css, combobox, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm running into a weird situation with styling the combo box button in javafx. Currently, I have

```
.combo-box .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.combo-box .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-size: 5;
}
```

which sets the background color of the button to be white, and the arrow to be black. This is fine if the combo box is not editable. However, if I had the combo box editable, this CSS doesn't get applied.

Does anyone know how I can style the drop down button if the combo box is editable?

```
public class SSCCE extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    ComboBox editable = new ComboBox();
    editable.setEditable(true);
    editable.setPrefWidth(125);

    ComboBox notEditable = new ComboBox();
    notEditable.setEditable(false);
    notEditable.setPrefWidth(125);

    root.getChildren().addAll(editable, notEditable);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();

    StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet("/theme/styles/ComboBox.css");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: added in edit. Obviously you'll have to change path to CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StyleManager` is not part of the public API, and I don't know what it does.

Use the standard mechanism for adding a stylesheet:

```
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/theme/styles/ComboBox.css").toExternalForm());
```

[image]

The top image is using `StyleManager`: the bottom image uses `scene.getStylesheets().add(...)`

Comment: I understand the risks of using Style Manager since it is not a public API. I am also using some of Suns private API for other things. This doesn't solve the issue though.

Comment: I tested it both with your code (didn't apply css to the editable ComboBox's arrow) and with mine; using `scene.getStylesheets().add(...)` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Interesting. With my application, it would be a hassle for me to do scene.getStylesheets().add(...) for each stage shown (since there could be many). I kind of assumed StyleManager applied all CSS style sheets to every scene. My bad though, I marked yours as correct. I guess I'll have to investigate further with StyleManager.

Comment: One possible solution (in Java 8) would be to modify modena.css, and then call `setUserAgentStylesheet(...)` in your `start(..)` method. It's not an ideal solution, obviously, as you would not benefit from bug fixes in later releases of modena.css without manually updating your modified css file.

Comment: I have tried this thing but not working with editable combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Hope is not to late to answer your question... in order to change the arrow color we need to access it by the CSS combo-box-base class and his substructure until we get to the arrow:

```
.combo-box-base > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

You can find it in the [CSS reference for Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#ComboBox)